# Batch to PowerShell Language Conversion

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

My batch script in DOS is processing way to slow, so someone recomended I use powershell. I'm running it now for my first time on windows, but I've never used it before today. I hear it's similar to batch scripting, so I'm currently converting my batch script into a powershell script. Below is my script so far half way through conversion:

```
# ask user for network share and file that they would like to search
$textFilePath = Read-Host Please enter filesystem location of "filenames.txt". Include drive letter or // at start of path
$uncPath = Read-Host Please enter the UNC path you would like to search. Include // at start of path.

# REM check if network path is available. If it is, search network directory for files with same name as the strings in filenames.txt
IF (Test-Path %uncPath%) {
    echo Network Path Exists. Searching %uncPath% for files with same name and extension as filenames in the filenames.txt file 
    for (/r %uncPath% %%G IN (*)) {for (/F "tokens=*" %%i in (%textFilePath%)) {if (%%~nxG==%%i) {echo %%~nxG,%%~fG >> filenamesOutput.txt}}}
    pause
}

IF (!(Test-Path exist %uncPath%)) {
    echo File not found
    GOTO:userInput
}
```

I'm currently learning the powershell commands as I go and changing the batch command to powershell. Help with conversion would be appreciated.

AFter Edit:

Here's my original batch script:

```
@echo off

echo Please enter filesystem location of "filenames.txt". (Include Drive letter or // at start of path)
set /p textFilePath=Enter The Value:%=%
:userInput
REM ask user for network share and file that they would like to search
echo Please enter the UNC path you would like to search. (Include // at start of path)
set /p uncPath=Enter The Value:%=%

REM check if network path is available. If it is, search network directory for files with same name as the strings in filenames.txt
IF exist %uncPath% (
    echo Network Path Exists. Searching %uncPath% for files with same name and extension as filenames in the filenames.txt file
    for /r %uncPath% %%G IN (*) DO for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (%textFilePath%) DO if %%~nxG==%%i echo %%~nxG,%%~fG >> filenamesOutput.txt
    pause
)

IF NOT exist %uncPath% (
    echo File not found
    GOTO:userInput
)
```

After 2nd Edit:

```
$VerbosePreference = "continue"

# ask user for network share and file that they would like to search
$textFilePath = Read-Host Please enter filesystem location of     "filenames.txt". Include drive letter or // at start of path
$uncPath = Read-Host Please enter the UNC path you would like to search. Include // at start of path.

# check if network path is available. If it is, search network directory for     files with same name as the strings in filenames.txt
IF (Test-Path $uncPath){
    echo "Network Path Exists. Searching $uncPath for files with same name and extension as filenames in the filenames.txt file"
    foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $uncPath -Recurse) {
        # Get-Content reads in a file, line by line
        foreach($line in Get-Content $_.FullName) {
            # if goes in here
            if($file.Name -eq $line){
                echo $file.Name
                "{0},{1}" -f $file.Name,$file.FullName | Out-File filenamesOutput2.txt -Append
            }
        }
    }
Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
}



IF (!(Test-Path $uncPath)){
    echo "UNC path not found"
    Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
    $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
}
```

Comment: It will probably be easier to help you with the original batch script rather than your hybrid :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Sorry. Didn't think about it. Included my original batch script above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Variables:

In PowerShell, variable references are always prefixed with `$` (much like in PHP or Perl).

So any variable you would assign and dereference in cmd/batch as:

```
set /p varname= somevalue
echo %varname%
```

Would in PowerShell be treated as (notice no difference between assigning and dereferencing):

```
$varname = "varvalue"
Write-Host $varname
```

So your `exists`/`Test-Path` statements should be:

```
if(Test-Path $uncPath){
    # Loops in here
    # "#" starts is a single-line comment btw
}
```

---

### For loop:

In cmd, the `for` loop construct behaves different depending on the first switch:

- `for /r` roughly means "loop recursively through filesystem tree"
- `for /f` roughly means "loop through tokens in a file"

it should be noted that cmd for loops use parameters, denoted by the prefix `%%` (like `%%G` or `%%i` in your example)

PowerShell doesn't have this concept and just uses variables in loops. Thus, your `for /r` and `for /f` loops become:

```
# Get-ChildItem is equivalent to the "dir" command
# The -Recurse is pretty self-explanatory ( = /S) 
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $uncPath -Recurse) {
   # Get-Content reads in a file, line by line
   foreach($line in Get-Content $textFilePath) {
        # if goes in here
    }
}
```

---

### Parameter modifiers:

In cmd, a parameter (like `%%G`) can be [modified using a tilde (`~`)](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true) followed by a sequence of modifier characters.

- `%%~nG` means "treat `%%G` as a path, return the name without extension"
- `%%~xG` means "treat `%%G` as a path, return the file extension"

so `%%~nxG` naturally means "return filename WITH extension".

In PowerShell, everything is a .NET object, and in the case of `$file`, it's a [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object. From the `FileInfo` object, the filename (WITH the extension) is stored in the `Name` property, so your `if` statement:

```
if %%~nxG==%%i
```

becomes:

```
if($file.Name -eq $line){
    # echo and output goes in here
}
```

- `%%~fG` means "treat `%%G` as a path, give me the full rooted path"

Again, the fact that `$file` is a `FileInfo` object comes in handy, the full path can be accessed from the `FullName` property:

```
"{0},{1}" -f $file.Name,$file.FullName | Out-File filenamesOutput.txt -Append
```

The `-f` operator is a simplified syntactic shortcut to [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx), .NET's version of `sprintf` if you will.

---

Ultimately resulting in something like:

```
# ask user for network share and file that they would like to search
$textFilePath = Read-Host 'Please enter filesystem location of "filenames.txt". Include drive letter or \\ at start of path'
$uncPath = Read-Host 'Please enter the UNC path you would like to search. Include \\ at start of path.'

# check if network path is available. If it is, search network directory for files with same name as the strings in filenames.txt
if (Test-Path $uncPath) {
    Write-Host "Network Path Exists. Searching $uncPath for files with same name and extension as filenames in the filenames.txt file"

    foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $uncPath) {
        foreach($line in Get-Content $textFilePath) {
            if($file.Name -eq $line){
                '"{0}","{1}"' -f $file.Name,$file.FullName | Out-File filenamesOutput.txt -Append
            }
        }
    }
    pause
} else {
    Write-Host "File not found"
}
```

Comment: This is so much information, thank you! I have the script written in power shell except for one line, line # 13 with the echo statement. For that line, do I echo out `$file.Name` and `$file.Fullname` to a text file with a comma in between them to write to that text file, or do I use `Write-Host`?

Comment: If you use `Write-Host`, the string it gets written directly to the host (the console window) and never ends up in the file. In my answer, the `"{0}" -f $var` expression constructs a string, which is then piped to the `Out-File` cmdlet which writes it to the file

Comment: I will read more and digest this through the day today, but thank you for all of the info, I learned a lot very quickly.

Comment: Is there a way to put quotes around the $`file.Name` and `$file.FullName`?

Comment: Use single-quotes around the format string: `'"{0}","{1}"' -f $file.Name,$file.FullName`

Comment: Or escape the double-quotes by using two consecutive ones: `"""{0}"",""{1}""" -f $file.Name,$file.FullName`

Comment: I'm getting an error with the script below my 2nd edit. The error is: `Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At //serverFilesystemLocation\searchNetworkScriptFINAL3.ps1:12 char:38+foreach($line in Get-Content $_.FullName) {
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand` Are there any work arounds to this? I think $_.FullName is underfined

Comment: What did you input as `$uncPath`? Try changing `Get-ChildItem $uncPath -Recurse` to `Get-ChildItem $uncPath -File -Recurse`

Comment: uncPath was `C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\8.25.15\script\diffVersionsOfScript\randoooo2`. I think the issue was I didn't surround the string with quotes.

Comment: Sorry, should be `Get-Content $textFilePath`, not `Get-Content $_.FullName`, my bad

Comment: No Worries With the changes you just suggested, and when I put in my `uncPath` in quotes, I only get one error: `Exception calling "ReadKey" with "1" argument(s): "The method or operation is not implemented."
At Folder/searchNetworkScriptFINAL3.ps1:29 char:5
+     $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotImplementedException`

Comment: PowerShell already has a `pause` function you can use instead of ReadKey()

Comment: yea. I took the `ReadKey()` lines out.

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much, but after that revision I still got an error. It states: `Get-Content : An object at the specified pathC:\Users\randoooo2\file.pdf does not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.At searchNetworkScriptFINAL3.ps1:12 char:26+foreach($line in Get-Content $file.FullName) {+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+ CategoryInfo       : ObjectNotFound: (System.String[]:String[]) [Get-Content], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorIdItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand`